# Combine two discrete functions with non-overlapping domains

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Set $S$ consists of at least 2 non-overlapping subsets $S_1$ and $S_2$. 
$S_1$ is the domain of a discrete function $F$. $S_2$ is the domain of a different discrete function $G$. Is there a way to combine the two domains, so that the combined function could take any input from the new domain and give the same output as if the original function were used? For example: 
For all $x \in \mathbb N^0$:
If $x$ is odd, $F(x)=x+1$ 
If $x$ is even, $G(x)=\frac x2$

Is it possible to get rid of the 'ifs' and make a single function that would take *any* non-negative integer $x$ as input and give proper $y$ as the output, *as if* those were two different functions used?
 Clarification edit: ideally the combination of $F$ and $G$ should become a single closed algebraic formula. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below, I will specify a clarification that is needed here from you, but first let me construct what you probably already see, even with the flaw you find in it (which I will address below).  In general, the answer is Yes if $F$ and $G$ take values in the same scalar field (say, the reals): let $S = S_{1} \cup S_{2}$, and make a new function, $H(x)$, take the value of the $F$ or the $G$, accordingly as $x$ comes from $S_{1}$ or $S_{2}$.

Now, it sounds like you want a closed algebraic formula for $H$, instead of the "if"s.  Not sure this can be achieved completely, but the "if"s can be "packed away" into the algebra.  Let $I_{S_{1}}(x)$ be the indicator (aka membesrhip) function of $S_{1}$.  I.e., for $x \in S$, put $I_{S_{1}}(x) = 1$ if $x \in S_{1}$, and $=0$ otherwise.  Similarly introduce $I_{S_{2}}(x)$.  Then we can write
$$
H(x) = I_{S_{1}}(x) F(x) + I_{S_{2}}(x) G(x) \quad \mbox{ for } x \in S.
$$

Comment: Yes, ideally H should become a closed algebraic formula. But the indicator function helps too and I didn't know about it, thanks!